# MySQL import error in GitHub Actions with laravel

Tags: laravel, github-actions

I am trying to import an SQL file with the following command using GitHub actions workflow .sql file contains some test data which will be further used to run unit test cases in laravel.

I am unable to understand if the file path is wrong or import command is wrong. I have saved SQL file on the root directory of laravel.

I am facing the following error:

> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Below is the command used in the `.yml` file which is used in the workflow for laravel.

```yaml
- name: Importing MYSQL file
  env:
    DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1
    DB_CONNECTION: mysql
    DB_DATABASE: test
    DB_PORT: ${{ job.services.mysql.ports[3306] }}
    DB_USER: root
    DB_PASSWORD: password
  run: mysql -u root -p password -h localhost --port=3306 test < request_data.sql
```

Implementing database seeds will be a bit time-consuming that's why I'm using this way to import `.sql` data. Also, I am a bit new to this workflow thing. let me know if there is some issue in running the command or if it is not possible to import an existing `.sql` file.

Please note the migrations I have run using the workflow file are running successfully.

The following code is used to create MySQL service:

```yaml
jobs:
  phpunit:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    env:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
    ports:
      - 33306:3306
    options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
```

Here's the workflow error:

[image: workflow error image]

[image]

[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error in the above screenshot is not visible. Do you see any details there in the raw logs?

Comment: error code is same I mentioned in question and let me know how I can check raw logs in GitHub actions

Comment: Sure. Also, please confirm if you've used the same image i.e. `mysql:5.7` locally and whether it's working fine on your side.

Comment: yes I have same mysql even export mysqldump does not seems to work for github actions.

Comment: Right. Could you please add a small `.sql` file also? I'll try to reproduce this on my side.

Comment: Thanks! Is that the complete workflow in the question that you're using? Could you please combine that to make it one complete workflow and add if anything is missing? Looks like `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` is missing. And, the file `.sql` file doesn't have DB creation query in it i.e. for creating the `test` DB.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ku6sav3gx9e2aoe/request_data.sql?dl=0 for sample .sql file which I am trying to import

Comment: @Azeem
mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 33306 -uroot -ppassword -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'test'"

this command helps to make sure database already created and exists there and we dont need to create database

Comment: I tried to reproduce this scenario in this workflow (https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/3960617373/workflow) with a custom `.sql` file. It's working fine (https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/3960617373/jobs/6785004958). Regarding `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`, I found out that there's a preinstalled MySQL in the runner which is disabled by default. And, this command (and there are other variants too with `systemctl` and `service` commands) is used to start that MySQL instance.

Comment: Here's the link to that issue where it says it's been disabled: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/576 (comment: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/576#issuecomment-600637922)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your scenario with a small `.sql` file but it's working fine with the [`mysql:5.7` Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

Here's the complete [workflow](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/3960617373/workflow):

```yaml
name: MySQL Import Test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  import:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      mysql:
        # https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: test
        ports:
          - 33306:3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

    steps:
    - name: Import MySQL file
      env:
        SQL: |
          SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
          START TRANSACTION;
          SET time_zone = "+00:00";
          CREATE TABLE `person` (
            `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
            `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL
          );
          INSERT INTO `person` (`id`, `name`, `email`)
          VALUES
            (111, 'abc', 'abc@email.com'),
            (222, 'def', 'def@email.com'),
            (333, 'ghi', 'ghi@email.com'),
            (444, 'jkl', 'jkl@email.com');
          ALTER TABLE `person` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
          COMMIT;
      run: |
        mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 33306 -uroot -ppassword -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'test';" 2>/dev/null
        echo "$SQL" > person.sql
        echo "--- SQL ---"
        cat person.sql
        echo "--- --- ---"
        echo "Importing from person.sql file"
        mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 33306 -uroot -ppassword test < person.sql 2>/dev/null
        echo "Checking the imported data"
        mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 33306 -uroot -ppassword test <<< 'SELECT id,name,email FROM person;' 2>/dev/null
```

**Output**

```
Database (test)
test
--- SQL ---
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `person` (`id`, `name`, `email`)
VALUES
  (111, 'abc', 'abc@email.com'),
  (222, 'def', 'def@email.com'),
  (333, 'ghi', 'ghi@email.com'),
  (444, 'jkl', 'jkl@email.com');
ALTER TABLE `person` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
COMMIT;

--- --- ---
Importing from person.sql file
Checking the imported data
id  name    email
111 abc abc@email.com
222 def def@email.com
333 ghi ghi@email.com
444 jkl jkl@email.com
```

---

Apart from that, the command i.e. `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` (and its other variants e.g. `service` and `systemctl`) is for the preinstalled MySQL. Here's the relevant issue: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/576

In your scenario, as the requirement is to test on a Docker container, issuing commands for the locally installed MySQL (which is disabled by default) is not required at all.

Comment: I was also able to import sql file using 
mysql -Dtest -uroot -ppassword -h127.0.0.1 -P33306 < "request_data.sql"

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. you tried both way. using sql commands and sql file.

Comment: @Ankit: That's good to hear. Cheers! :)

Comment: @Ankit: You're welcome! Yes, I needed to verify if the imported data indeed was there that's why I used the second inline query instead of adding it to file. However, the mix of the default preinstalled MySQL and one via docker was a good find. :)

Comment: I was using localhost at place of 127.0.0.1 before resolving and that didn't work and i didn't notice for long.

Comment: @Ankit: Right. Also, the preinstalled one and the one in the docker both have different configuration settings via env vars and different defaults too. That needed some figuring out too on my part. Finally, it's working. That's the good thing.