# Unable to access mysql database ceated in GitHub actions

Tags: mysql, github, github-actions, mysql-python, cicd

I have been trying to automate my test and deployment for my portfolio project with GitHub actions for the past two days, and i am new to it. i wrote a script to set up a test environment for a python application and i used an external action to get mysql set up on the runner, and i keep getting an access denied error when i try to access the database from root or any user i created during the setup of the database, i was thinking maybe there is a conflict in character types, because i used the same password, i even tried setting the password in github secretes and calling it as a variable but still got the same thing.

this is the workflow file for a python application and i used an external action to get mysql set up on the runner here is the workflow file

main.yml

```
name: test-deploy-app
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is deploying  to server
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]
jobs:
  run-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
        SH_HOST: 'localhost'
        SH_PWD: 'Sch_t3st_#3#_pwd'
        SH_USER: 'sh_test_user'
        SH_ENV: 'test'
        SH_DATABASE: 'sh_test_db'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: "3.8"

      - uses: mirromutth/mysql-action@v1.1
        with:
          host port: 3800 # Optional, default value is 3306. The port of host
          container port: 3307 # Optional, default value is 3306. The port of container
          character set server: 'utf8' # Optional, default value is 'utf8mb4'. The '--character-set-server' option for mysqld
          collation server: 'utf8_general_ci' # Optional, default value is 'utf8mb4_general_ci'. The '--collation-server' option for mysqld
          mysql version: '8.0' # Optional, default value is "latest". The version of the MySQL
          mysql database: 'sh_test_db' # Optional, default value is "test". The specified database which will be create
          mysql root password: 'password' # Required if "mysql user" is empty, default is empty. The root superuser password
          mysql user: 'developer' # Required if "mysql root password" is empty, default is empty. The superuser for the specified database. Can use secrets, too
          mysql password: 'me' # Required if "mysql user" exists. The password for the "mysql user"
      - run: mysql --version
      - run: ls
      - run: sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
      - run: sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
      - run: pip3 install mysqlclient
      - run: pip3 install SQLAlchemy
      - run: sudo systemctl start mysql.service
      - run: cat setup_mysql_test.sql | sudo mysql -u root --password=password
      - name: start test
        run: python3 -m unittest discover
```

I tried this to set up and test my python application using unittest, but i always get a mysql access error showing that my password is wrong, on the line that has this code cat setup_mysql_test.sql | sudo mysql -u root --password==password

i also tried a different approach where i installed the mysql server my self without an external action and i pre seeded the installation root password with debconf-set-selections but i still got the same response of access denied. below if the workflow visualization showing the error

[workflow vizualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQA1d.png)

the file that contains the test sql script i am trying to pass to the database

setup_mysql_test.sql

```
-- prepares a MySQL server for the project for testing

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS sh_test_db;
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'sh_test_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Sch_t3st_#3#_pwd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `sh_test_db`.* TO 'sh_test_user'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON `performance_schema`.* TO 'sh_test_user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

this will create the test database and the test user.

all i am trying to do is setup a mysql database and execute this mysql command to configure a database and user that the sqlalchemy orm from my application can use.

also, i tried changing the port on the container and host to 3306 which i thought to be mysql default port but then it refuses to start and fails on this run command on the workflow `sudo systemctl start mysql.service` giving me this error,

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I would be very gratefull to whoever can help, i am so close to my deadline thanks

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75541794/how-to-grant-permissions-to-mysql-in-github-actions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75169859/mysql-import-error-in-github-actions-with-laravel.

Comment: Thanks, I used the pre installed mysql server and it worked fine.. I never knew the runner had those. Thanks @Azeem

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. needs to update the mysql client.

```
- name: install mysql client
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y  mysql-client
```